# If $M$ is Lebesgue measurable set of $\mathbb R$ and $M^2$ is Lebesgue measurable set of $\mathbb R^2$, does $M^2=M\otimes M$?

Tags: measure-theory

If $\mathcal M$ is Lebesgue measurable set of $\mathbb R$ and $\mathcal M^2$ is Lebesgue measurable set of $\mathbb R^2$, does $\mathcal M^2=\mathcal M\otimes\mathcal M$ ?

So, I think the answer is no, but I can't prove it. My intuition is, since $$\mathcal M\otimes \mathcal M=\sigma \{A\times B\mid A,B\in \mathcal M\},$$
I think that if $E\in \mathcal M\otimes \mathcal M$, then $$E^y:=\{x\mid (x,y)\in E\}\quad \text{and}\quad E^x:=\{y\mid (x,y)\in E\},$$
has to be $\mathcal M-$measurable for each $x$ and $y$, whereas, in $\mathcal M^2$, since nulls sets are measurable, we could take $E=\{0\}\times \mathcal N$ where $\mathcal N$ is a non measurable set of $\mathbb R$, and since the measure of $E$ is $0$, it's measurable, but $E^0=\mathcal N$ is not.

But unfortunately, I can't prove that if $E\in \mathcal M\otimes\mathcal M$, then $E^x$ is $\mathcal M-$measurable for all $x$ and $E^y$ is $\mathcal M-$measurable for all $y$, and I can't find a counter example.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: The answer is not. If $\mathrm{V}$ is the Vitali set (non Lebesgue measurable) then $\mathrm{V} \times \{0\}$ is measurable relative to Lebesgue measure in $\mathbf{R}^2.$

Comment: To prove that $\mathscr{M}^2$ is not equal to $\mathscr{M} \otimes \mathscr{M}$ one needs to provide an example of a set in one that does not belong to the other one. Now, $\mathscr{M} \otimes \mathscr{M}$ is always a subset of $\mathscr{M}^2.$ Thus, to show they are different, I gave you an example in $\mathscr{M}^2$ that does not belong to $\mathscr{M} \otimes \mathscr{M}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually true that if $\mathscr{X}$ and $\mathscr{Y}$ are two sigma fields, then for a set $\mathrm{A} \times \mathrm{B}$ to belong to $\mathscr{Z} \mathop{=}\limits^{\mathrm{def.}} \mathscr{X} \otimes \mathscr{Y}$ it is necessary and sufficient that $\mathrm{A}$ should belong to $\mathscr{X}$ and $\mathrm{B},$ to $\mathscr{Y}.$

The sufficiency is just definition. The necessity is tricky. For a set $\mathrm{U}$ in $\mathscr{Z},$ define the section $\mathrm{U}^y = \{x: (x, y) \in \mathrm{U}\}.$ The set of $\mathrm{U}$ such that $\mathrm{U}^y$ belongs to $\mathscr{X}$ is all of $\mathscr{Z}.$ If $\mathscr{L}$  is such set of $\mathrm{U},$ the $\mathscr{L}$ is a sigma algebra containing the rectangles, hence all of $\mathscr{Z}.$

Comment: PS: I deleted my comments because the answer is better. And also the answer had little to do with projections. I learnt measure theory quite some time ago, actually.

Comment: Thank you (and very nice proof by the way) :) (very elegant).